# determining the end of an asynchronous loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

In the code attached i am looking to run the function `returnFile` after all database querys have run, but the problem is that i am unable to tell which response will be the last from inside of the query response, so what I was thinking was to separate the loops and just have the last callback run the `returnFile` function but that would dramatically slow things down.

```
for (var i = 0, len = articleRevisionData.length; i < len; i++) {
    tagNames=[]
    console.log("step 1, "+articleRevisionData.length+" i:"+i);
    if(articleRevisionData[i]["tags"]){
        for (var x = 0, len2 = articleRevisionData[i]["tags"].length; x < len2; x++) {
            console.log("step 2, I: "+i+" x: "+x+articleRevisionData[i]["articleID"])
            tagData.find({"tagID":articleRevisionData[i]["tags"][x]}).toArray( function(iteration,len3,iterationA,error, resultC){
                console.log("step 3, I: "+i+" x: "+x+" iteration: "+iteration+" len3: "+len3)
                if(resultC.length>0){
                   tagNames.push(resultC[0]["tagName"]);
                }
                    //console.log("iteration: "+iteration+" len: "+len3)
               if(iteration+1==len3){
                    console.log("step 4, iterationA: "+iterationA+" I: "+iteration)
                    articleRevisionData[iterationA]["tags"]=tagNames.join(",");
               } 
            }.bind(tagData,x,len2,i));
        }
    }
    if(i==len-1){
        templateData={
            name:userData["firstName"]+" "+userData["lastName"],
            articleData:articleData,
            articleRevisionData:articleRevisionData
        }
        returnFile(res,"/usr/share/node/Admin/anonymousAttempt2/Admin/Articles/home.html",templateData);
    }
}
```

Comment: Other people have already solved this problem. I'd suggest using something like Caolan's AyncJS library. Specifically, eachLimit :
http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.eachLimit

Comment: use Promise's and more specifically Promise.all - no library required

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks for the idea but I'm unsure as to when id be able to call the resolve function, as if i call it at the end of the loop all the queries may have not returned, and if i want to call it from inside of a query, i have no way of knowing that that query is the last one?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with what `tagData.find` does in your code (assuming that's the asynchronous function) to begin to explain how Promises may be able to help you. There is a way without Promises, keeping a count of running queries and calling the code that runs when all finished when the running queries are all  complete - again, no idea what `tagData.find` is to help

Comment: @JaromandaX `tagData` is the mongodb collection reference, and `.find` is the find function in mongodb

Comment: is `.toArray` called asynchronously on the result of `.find`?

Comment: @JaromandaX that would be correct

Answer (score 0):

It is rarely a good idea to call an asynchronous function from within a loop since, as you've discovered, you cannot know when all the calls complete (which is the nature of asynchrony.)

In your example, it's important to note that **all** of your async calls run concurrently, which can consume more system resources than you might wish.

I've found that the best solution to these kinds of problems is to use events to manage execution flow, as in:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');

const emitter = new EventEmitter();

let iterations = articleRevisionData.length;

// start up state
emitter.on('start', () => {
  // do setup here
  emitter.emit('next_iteration');
});

// loop state
emitter.on('next_iteration', () => {
  if(iterations--) {
    asyncFunc(args, (err,result) => {
      if(err) {
        emitter.emit('error', err);
        return;
      }
      // do something with result 
      emitter.emit('next_iteration');
    });
    return;
  }
  // no more iterations
  emitter.emit('complete');
});

// error state
emitter.on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(`processing failed on iteration ${iterations+1}: ${e.toString()}`);
});

// processing complete state
emitter.on('complete', () => {
  // do something with all results
  console.log('all iterations complete');
});

// start processing
emitter.emit('start');
```

Note how simple and clean this code is, lacking any "callback hell", and how easy it is to visualize program flow.

It is also worth noting that you can express **every** kind of execution control (doWhile, doUntil, map/reduce, queue workers, etc.) using events and since event handling is at the very core of Node, you'll find using them in this manner will outperform most, if not all, other solutions.

See [Node Events](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter) for more information on event handling in Node.